# Creating a host volume mapping to contents inside a directory in the container , so that the contents can be viewed and edited from host

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, mount, volumes

Let's say I have a directory **/var/www/html** inside the container. I want to view it's contents outside in let's say **~/my_user/sites** ( folder sites is not yet created ). I know I can use the volume mapping in docker-compose as follows-

```
volumes:
  - ~/my_user/sites:/var/www/html
```

But whenever I do this, the directory /var/www/html inside the container is mounted to an empty directory, therefore itself become empty.
I know that this is how mounting is supposed to work but isn't there a way by which I can get access to the contents of the container in the host directory structure itself.

Also, if you have an easy workaround this then please mention that.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the original source tree from source control.  You can't directly mount a container's files to the host or directly edit the files, and in any case changes you make inside a container will be lost as soon as the container exits.  That is: any sort of volume mount _always_ hides the content that was originally present in the image.

Comment: The "Mount directory in Container" question I linked to describes the sorts of changes you'd need to make in the image to replicate its files to a mounted volume.  However, if you can do this, you probably already have the original source files.